# Python 3.7.2, end = " " in my for loop removes all text when ran in console?

Tags: python, list, function

I am creating this encoding/decoding program in python. (3.7.2). You input string into the program, it converts it to a list, reverses the list, switches some items around to make it more cryptic. The decoding function basically is the opposite of that. In my for loop that prints out each letter at the end of the process (for both encoder and decoder), it won't print out the final result when I run the file through console (CommandPrompt) However it works perfectly in default python IDLE. I've used `end = " "` in my for loop to remove any the unwanted spaces.

I have tried making variables equal the final output of the for loop and printing them but that still had the same error.

Here is my code:

```
import time, os # imports modules

def main():

    os.system('cls')

    inp=input("Encoder or Decoder: E or D.\n\npython@user$ ") #Asks which  tool they want to use (Encoder/Decoder)

    if inp in ("E", "e"): #Sees if user chooses encoder.
        os.system('cls') # clears the screen.
        encode() #Goes to 'encode' function.

    else: 
        decode() #goes to 'decode' function.


def encode():

    inp=input ("What do you wish to encode? - Must be a sentence\n\npython@user$ ") # Retrievs what the user wants to translate.

    list_of_inp = list(inp) #turns inputted string value into a list where every character is an item.

    reversed_list = (list_of_inp[::-1]) #Reverses the list.
                                                                            #--|
    reversed_list[2], reversed_list[6] = reversed_list[6], reversed_list[2] #  |
    reversed_list[1], reversed_list[9] = reversed_list[9], reversed_list[1] #   ---- Switches values of the list to make it more rnadom.
    reversed_list[7], reversed_list[4] = reversed_list[4], reversed_list[7] #  |
                                                                            #--|

    for item in reversed_list:
        print (item, end = "") #Prints every character in list and removes unwanted spaces.

    os.system('pause') #Press ant key to continue.

    time.sleep(1) #waits one second.

    main()

def decode():


    inp=input ("What do you wish to decode?\n\npython@user$ ") # Retrievs what the user wants to translate.

    list_of_inp = list(inp) #turns inputted string value into a list where every character is an item.

                                                                    #--|                            
    list_of_inp[2], list_of_inp[6] = list_of_inp[6], list_of_inp[2] #  |
    list_of_inp[1], list_of_inp[9] = list_of_inp[9], list_of_inp[1] #   ---- Switches back the items.
    list_of_inp[7], list_of_inp[4] = list_of_inp[4], list_of_inp[7] #  |
                                                                    #--|

    reversed_list = (list_of_inp[::-1]) #Reverses the list to normal.

    for ch in reversed_list:
        print (ch, end = "")#Prints every character in list and removes unwanted spaces.

    os.system('pause') #Press any key to continue.

    time.sleep(1) #Waits 1 second.

    main() #returns to 'main' function.

main() #calls main function to start the program.
```

It is expected to print the final result of the list, then "Press any key to continue" then go to my main function. (main menu). However it just displays "Press any key to continue", after pressing any key it takes you back the main function and the output is joined to the start of my text in main(). Even though it says `os.system('cls')` at the start.

Comment: works fine for me in console.  My console doesn't like the "cls" and "pause" commands.  Try commenting those out.

Comment: This is what it prints to me when I input what I want to be encoded, its the output mixed with the main() - https://gyazo.com/bc1132d2eac8d856c17525c0097bb58e

Comment: That is because your previous print statement that was used to print the encoded output has the `end=""` in it.  Just add an extra `print()` statement after that and outside of the loop.  This will force the next print statement to occur on the next line

Comment: Thank you, It ran perfectly